# In android data toast is ok, but I want to show data in a new page in listview , when i click a button

Tags: android

It shows database first data, but i want to show all data which number is 3 column table of each row, and after it will open after click a button and open this list in a new activity

```
//Read Database
public void readDB(View v) {
    SQLiteDatabase db2 = openOrCreateDatabase(" Result ", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    String strThree = "SELECT * FROM my_result";
    Cursor c = db2.rawQuery(strThree, null);
    c.moveToNext();

    String grade = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Grade_Point"));
    String ss = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Subject_Name"));

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Subject Name is "+ss+" and Gragde point is"+grade , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the extracted values from your column 3 into a variable preferably in an arraylist. Then On the click of your button send it to your activity and populate your listview in that activity in the onCreate() method of that activity. Example below(Not tested)

```
ArrayList<String> col_3 = new ArrayList<String>();
void readDB(View v){
    SQLiteDatabase db2 = openOrCreateDatabase(" Result ", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    String strThree = "SELECT * FROM my_result";
    Cursor c = db2.rawQuery(strThree, null);
    while(c.moveToNext()!=null){
        col_3.add(c.getString(2)) //since 3rd column
    }
}
```

Now on the onClick of your button send it to the destination activity via intents

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("col_3_data", col_3);
startActivity(intent);
```

onCreate() method of your destination Activity will be something like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(); 
ArrayList col_value =new ArrayList<String>();
col_value = i.getStringArrayListExtra("col_3_data");
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_lsitview); //my_listview is your listview where you want to display your data
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, col_value );
lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest instead of creating a new activity, you can create a `dialog` with `listview`, follow one of the following tutorials:
http://envyandroid.com/creating-listdialog-with-images-and-text/
http://www.edumobile.org/android/custom-listview-in-a-dialog-in-android/